# How to send image using flask Socket-Io

Tags: sockets, socket.io, flask-socketio

I am very novice in Flask Socket.IO, I am trying to find a solutions where I can send images using Flask Socket.IO. Help would be highly appreciated.

I am using this application.py file to emit a saved image from the project directory

```
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, copy_current_request_context
from random import random
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread, Event


__author__ = 'slynn'

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
app.config['DEBUG'] = True


socketio = SocketIO(app, async_mode=None, logger=True, engineio_logger=True)

#random number Generator Thread
thread = Thread()
thread_stop_event = Event()

def randomNumberGenerator():
    print("Making random numbers")

    while not thread_stop_event.isSet():

        with open('savedImage.jpg', 'rb') as f:
            image_data = f.read()

        socketio.emit('my_response', {'image': image_data}, namespace='/test')
        socketio.sleep(2)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@socketio.on('connect', namespace='/test')
def test_connect():
    global thread
    print('Client connected')

    if not thread.is_alive():
        print("Starting Thread")
        thread = socketio.start_background_task(randomNumberGenerator)

@socketio.on('disconnect', namespace='/test')
def test_disconnect():
    print('Client disconnected')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app)
```

Using application1.js file to receive the binary form of the image to the client

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + '/test');
    var numbers_received = [];
    socket.on('my_response', function(msg) {

            let arrayBufferView = new Uint8Array(msg['image']);
            console.log(arrayBufferView);

            var blob = new Blob( [ arrayBufferView ], { type: "image/jpeg" } );
            //maintain a list of ten numbers
            var img_url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            console.log(img_url);
            document.getElementById("img_show").src = img_url;
        });

});
```

And using index.html to show the image, unfortunately nothing is visible

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.4.1/socket.io.min.js"></script>
    <script src="static/jscript/application1.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Asynchronous Flask Communication</h1>
    <p>Random numbers generated by the Flask server will appear below, asynchronously.</p>
    <p>Details <a href='https://www.shanelynn.ie/asynchronous-updates-to-a-webpage-with-flask-and-socket-io/' target='_blank'>here.</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
    
</div>

<div class="container" id="content">
    <div class="row">
        <h3>Image:</h3>
        <div id="img_show">
        </div> <!-- /#log -->
    </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I just fixed the issue. All codes written on the .py and .js file is correct except the html. Sorry for this little error. I just replaced <div id="img_show"> with <img src="", id="img_show"> on the html page. That's all needed to send over the image. Hope this will help someone.